# Can we use same global.r file for 2 apps in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

Can we use same global.r file for 2 apps?
I am developing apps using shiny and i want to know if i can use a same global.r file for more than one app
In my global.r file i am taking the data from a url in json format and making a data frame out of it.
And also is it the best way for optimization or not?

Comment: You can setup a script to download the JSON data and save the data.frame to something like rds (saveRDS/readRDS) on a scheduled basis. I don't know what technology you are are using but I would use chron and a basic shell script to run your R script. Then, in your shiny app you could simply refer to the rds location without having to run it over and over.

Comment: How do i do it in a scheduled basis?

Comment: library("RJSONIO")
startTime<-Sys.time()
json<<-fromJSON("https://edg.epa.gov/data.json",nullValue = NA)
df<-as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,json))
endTime<-Sys.time()
print(startTime-endTime)

Comment: this is not the actual url but i am storing this entire process in global.r and can i use that global.r in more than one app if yes then how?

Comment: Main problem with using rds is that my data keeps being updated so i want the rds to keep adding the new data to itself is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here's just an example function, that uses uncompressed serialization to load and update data:

```
append_rds <- function(new_rows) {
  df <- readRDS("path/to/file.rds")
  df <- rbind(df,new_rows)
  # not compressing it makes it faster - but larger on disk
  saveRDS(df, "path/to/file.rds", compress = FALSE)
}

new_rows <- pull_new_rows() # your download process here
append_rds(new_rows)
```

You would save this file as `run_me_frequently.R`. Then create a `chron` job or whatever system scheduler you use to run something like:

```
Rscipt path/to/update_data.R
```

Then in `global.r` you would use `readRDS("path/to/file.rds")` and this would always contain the most recent data based on your update schedule.